# How to fix **kwds & "file .csv not found" on pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to read a .csv file using pycharm for data science (i have all packages already installed), but i recieved an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Geoblast.csv' does not exist: b'Geoblast.csv'"
```

...also many errors in the .csv like:

```
line 685, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)" and "line 21, in <module>
dataraw = pd.read_csv('Geoblast.csv',skiprows=1,decimal=',',sep=',',dtype='str')
```

This is on pycharm. I've tried to put the .csv and de python algorithm in the same folder, but it doesn't work. I have numpy, pandas and scipy.lab already import in the algorithm

```
dataraw = pd.read_csv('Geoblast.csv',skiprows=1,decimal=',',sep=',',dtype='str')
dataraw = dataraw.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```

Kinds of errors:

1. ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Cristobal/Downloads/toichato.py", line 22, in <module>
       dataraw = pd.read_csv('Geoblast.csv',skiprows=1,decimal=',',sep=',',dtype='str')
   ```
2. ```
   dataraw = pd.read_csv('Geoblast.csv',skiprows=1,decimal=',',sep=',',dtype='str')
     File "C:\Users\Cristobal\PycharmProjects\Jirafa\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
   ```
3. ```
   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 687, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Geoblast.csv' does not exist: b'Geoblast.csv'
   ```

Comment: Does this file exist in the same directory you're running Python from? Apparently, it doesn't

Comment: You're talking about multiple (kinds of) errors, but you've only shown one error (plus random fragments of output which I suspect are part of the same error message).

Comment: try to add `print(os.getcwd())` and/or `print(os.listdir())` to see why the file is not found